# Another determinacy-related cardinal characteristic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy, cardinal-characteristics

*This question is a kind of "dual" to [an earlier one of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431054/is-this-cardinal-characteristic-trivial-number-of-strategies-needed-to-guarant).*

Although I don't know a reference for this, it's easy to show the following result:

> Suppose $G$ is a game in which neither player has a winning strategy. Then for any **countable** set $S$ of strategies for one player there is a single strategy for the other player beating every strategy in $S$.

(Here, "game" means "two-player perfect-information length-$\omega$ game on $\omega$" as usual in set theory.) Basically, the idea is to $(i)$ always have a "guess" at which strategy in $S$ your opponent is play, updating your guess whenever it's falsified, and $(ii)$ avoid making moves which place you in a losing position while also playing to beat your specific guess (see below for details).

Now given a game $G$ and $i\in\{0,1\}$, let $\sigma_{G,i}$ be the smallest cardinality of any set of strategies for player $i$ not each beaten by a single strategy for player $1-i$, and let $$\sigma_G=\max\{\sigma_{G,0},\sigma_{G,1}\},$$ with the convention that $\sigma_G=(2^{\aleph_0})^+$ if $G$ is determined. Define the "victory number" as $\mathfrak{v}=\min\{\sigma_G: G\subseteq\omega^\omega\}$ (identifying a game with its payoff set as usual).

> **Question**: is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathfrak{v}>\omega_1$?

As far as I can tell, even the theory $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH+\mathfrak{v}=2^{\aleph_0}}$ could be consistent! This seems blatantly silly, but I don't see an immediate contradiction.

*More generally, I'm interested in a particular pair of $\sigma$-ideals $\mathcal{I}^0_G,\mathcal{I}^1_G$ associated to an undetermined game $G$ as follows. Let $\mathcal{I}^i_{G,0}$ be the set of singleton sets of strategies for player $i$ in $G$, let $\mathcal{I}^i_{G,\lambda}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathcal{I}^i_{G,\alpha}$ for $\lambda$ limit, and let $\mathcal{I}^{i}_{G,\alpha+1}$ be the set of sets $S$ of strategies for player $i$ such that there is some $A\in\mathcal{I}^{1-i}_{G,\alpha}$ so that each strategy in $S$ is beaten by some strategy in $A$. Then let $\mathcal{I}^i_G=\bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathit{Ord}}\mathcal{I}^i_{G,\alpha}$. This question is effectively looking at just the first "layer" of these $\sigma$-ideals all at once, rather than focusing on any one game's entire $\sigma$-ideal, but ultimately it's the larger $\sigma$-ideals themselves that I'm really interested in.*

---

EDIT: For completeness, here's a proof of the result mentioned at the start of this question (I'm separately curious if there's a reference for this).

Suppose there is no winning strategy for player $1$ in $G$, and let $(\Sigma_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be a sequence of strategies for player $1$; we'll build a strategy $\Pi$ for player $2$ that beats each $\Sigma_n$ (the argument is basically the same if we swap the players).

Say that a game state is **good** if $1$ does not have a winning strategy from that state. By assumption the empty(/start) state is good, every even-length good state has only good successors, and every odd-length good state has at least one good successor. For each good game state $\sigma$ and each natural $n$ such that state $\sigma$ can be reached if player $1$ plays $\Sigma_n$, let $\Pi_{n,\sigma}$ be a strategy for player $2$ in "$G$-from-$\sigma$" such that

- playing according to $\Pi_{n,\sigma}$ from $\sigma$ never results in a non-good state, and
- playing $\Sigma_n\otimes\Pi_{n,\sigma}$ from $\sigma$ is a win for $2$.

Such a strategy must exist if $\sigma$ is good: otherwise, player $1$ has a winning strategy from $\sigma$ (play according to $\Sigma_n$ as long as we're in a good game state, otherwise switch to an appropriately-winning strategy when the option arises).

Now our strategy $\Pi$ can be defined. We start by assuming player $1$ will play according to $\Sigma_1$, and we play according to $\Pi_{1,\langle\rangle}$. If at some stage of play we see player $1$ deviate from $\Sigma_1$, we find the least $n$ such that their play so far is consistent with $\Sigma_n$ and shift our strategy to $\Pi_{n,\rho}$ where $\rho$ is the game state so far (if no such $n$ exists we just play randomly). We continue in this way: if at game state $\sigma$ we see a change in the least $k$ such that player $1$'s play so far is consistent with $\Sigma_k$, we shift to the corresponding $\Pi_{\sigma,k}$. As long as player $1$ does play according to one of the $\Sigma$-strategies, we'll eventually settle down on a $\Pi_{?,?}$-response and win.

Comment: I find this question extremely interesting and have been thinking about it since you posted, but no full examples yet. I have several half-examples.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKUOB8MN4Kc

Comment: Actually, I'm now wondering whether $\neg\mathsf{CH}+\forall G(\sigma_G\ge2^{\aleph_0})$ is blatantly silly after all. Maybe it's just a Martin's Axiom analogue?

Comment: I had a similar thought, but no proof.